# Not able to understand spring retry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I'm struggling with understanding @Retryable. What I need is to retry 3 times when I get 5xx Exception and if retry also fails then throw a custom exception in the recovery method. And if some other exception is thrown then catch it and throw a custom exception.

```
@Retryable(value = HttpServerErrorException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public String callToService(String key) {
        String response;
        try {
            response =  //assume a service call here
            
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new customException("some message");
        }
        return response;
}
    
@Recover
public void retryFailed(HttpServerErrorException httpServerErrorException) {
    throw new customException("some message");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case as you have added:
`@Retryable(value = HttpServerErrorException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))`

The `@Retryable` is used with:

1. `value = HttpServerErrorException.class`, so your method will be retried **only if** `HttpServerErrorException` is occure/thrown from your method code, and **Note:** if any other exception thrown retry will not be done, and recover method will also not be invoked, as recover method is only invoked with exception mentioned in value in @Retryable.
2. `maxAttempts = 3`, so it will retry executing your method 3 times by maximum
3. `backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000)`, so it will keep a delay of 3000ms in between retry.
4. And after retrying 3 times, if your method still not working, your method with `@Recover` will be envoked with the `HttpServerErrorException`

I hope it make sense and help yo understand the concept of `@Retryable`

Now to implement what you want you need to implement it as below:

```
@Retryable(value = HttpServerErrorException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public String callToService(String key) {
        String response;
        try {
            response =  //assume a service call here
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException httpServerErrorException) {
            throw httpServerErrorException;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException("some message");
        }
        return response;
}
    
@Recover
public void retryFailed(HttpServerErrorException httpServerErrorException) {
    //do whatever you want here, when HttpServerErrorException occured more than 3 times
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. Although when I tried above, retry was happening but recovery method wasn't getting called. Later found out that the method annotated with _Recover_ needs to have the same signature as the method annotated with _Retryable_